# Get div and its childs in code-behind and mail it without loosing the styles

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, html-email

I have an .aspx page with this body:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
        <%= this.OutputHtml  %>

    <CKEditor:CKEditorControl ID="CKEditor1" BasePath="/ckeditor/" runat="server" StylesSet="width: 0px; height: 0px;"></CKEditor:CKEditorControl>

    <asp:TextBox ID="MessageBuffer" runat="server" Text="" />

    <input type="button" id="Prepare_Mail" name="Prepare_Mail" runat="server" value="Prepare Mail" />
    <asp:Button ID="SendMail" runat="server" Text="Send Test Mail" OnClick="SendMail_Click" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
        $( '#Prepare_Mail' ).click(function() {
            alert( "Handler for .ckicl() called." );
            $('#MessageBuffer').val($('#nl'));
        });
    </script>
</form>
```

The string OutputHtml is my HTML-Markup, which is nearly fully editable with inline-ckeditor.
I get OutputHTML like this:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Server.MapPath("~/TextFiles/template2.txt"));
        String OutputHtml = sr.ReadToEnd();
        sr.Close();
    }
```

I am trying to gain access to the DIV-Box with the ID "nl" which is the main container in my template file. You see a little script at the bottom of the first code box, whicht doesn't work. I don't know why but the script is not even started at the Button-Click of "Prepare_Mail".

As for I am a newbie in asp, I don't know how to do the follwing:

- Get the div "nl" and all of its child content in a string variable in code-behind
- Send it via eMail (Sending the mail is not the problem, but keeping the styles is)

I hope i have provided enough information to help you helping me with this problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the full content of a div add a runat="server" attribute to de div, als make sure the ID attribute is typed with caps. like this:

```
<div ID="NL" runat="server">
```

In the backend:

```
string divContent = NL.innerHtml
```

Keeping the style is a problem. You can't send a CSS file so you'll have to use inline CSS. Not everything is supported so take a look at this:

https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

To see what you can do.

Comment: Yeah I have already copied my styles in my template2.txt file and deleted my style.css. I have added them like this at the beginning of NL:
`<style media="screen" type="text/css"> CSS rules here </style>`

EDIT: The runat="server" solution doesn't work because the div is not existing at the beginning of the livecycle. It is loaded in the Page_Load event like in the snippet above.

Answer (score 0):

You must Use Inline Css for this to work for you You can't send Css File as I remember